# How to use git tags (or other) to distinguish test/dev/prod release versions?

Tags: git

We are developing software that has major and minor releases during the year. We write testing code to allow Travis-CL to automate testing. We'd like to have a mechanism to filter out all testing code from the final release of the software. Can git tags be used for this? The tags would be applied to individual commits.

The kind of scenario that would be ideally available, would be like this:

`git checkout release-2016-01 --tag test-code`

To include commits that have been tagged as test-code.

I'm not sure what are best practices for this scenario, and how git can support that.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment instead of an answer, because it's probably not the answer you are looking for, but it's a really, really good practice that any commit ALSO includes the complementary test changes for whatever else that commit changed.  I get that you want to filter out the test code right before a release, but in practice, that would be a disaster and git doesn't have a nice mechanism for facilitating that either.  What you're looking to do can possibly be facilitated through other means, depending on what language and build tools you are working with.

Comment: Fair enough. But assuming committers used the tags properly, why would it be a disaster?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do here, what's `release-2016-01` ? Is it a branch? If so, you can't simultaneously ask git to checkout a branch and a tag. That makes no sense.

Comment: yes that's a branch. And the tag would identify commits that are part of the branch. If that's not supported, so be it.

Comment: I think the confusion here is what branches and tags are. In git, your entire history is a tree/graph and each commit is a "node" in that tree. Each tag or branch points to *a* specific node in that tree, analogous to how a C pointer would point to a memory location or a node. Using both a tag and a branch name to identify the commit doesn't make sense in this setup. You can use either/or but not both.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of going about this.

The first approach is a polished version of your suggestion.

You can have a release branch, and additional test commits, each test commit is tagged.

So your git tree looks something like this:

```
---O---O---O---O---O---O--- Release branch.
        \               \
         O               O
        test-2016-01    test-2016-02
```

So every time you run your tests, they're run against the commits tagged `test-<release id>`

Another approach would be, to write your test code, commit it, run the tests then apply a reverse diff for the patches with the testing code (this is very ugly).

```
---O---O---T---T'
```

where T is your test commit and T' is it's reverse.

The third approach would be, to keep your test code and your production code in separate repos, assuming you don't modify any of the your production code for the purposes of testing. If it is, you're not really testing the right thing...

The fourth and possibly the best approach is to leave the tests and testing framework/code in your main repo. If you have to restructure your code/repo to make it more modular to test, then that's a good investment of time.